# mysql command line escape - sign

Tags: mysql, command-line

I am trying to create a database but I can not figure out how to escape the - sign in the database name.

```
mysql> create database happy-face;
```

gives me an error

```
mysql> create database happyface;
```

works without problems
How can I escape the - sign in the name of the database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could quote the name with backticks

```
mysql> create database `happy-face`;
```

but you might want to avoid names that require backticks since it makes your life a little more complicated.